# Calculate the limit of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I tried solving this limit using the sendwich theorem:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt i}}$$

I supposed that i have two series 
$$ b_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt 1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt 1}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt 1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt 1}} = {\sqrt{2}-\sqrt 1}$$ 
and
$$ c_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}}=\infty$$

$$ b_n\le a_n\le c_n$$
But,
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} c_n \neq \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n  $$
I don't know what other series to use so that the limits can be equal. 
Can someone help me with this

Comment: Think about using an integral to approximate the denominator.

Comment: @saulspatz I dont know how to use the integral to approximate

Comment: Actually, I misread the problem.  My idea doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyse that series:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}} $$

Rationalise multiplying numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}$:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}=2(\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+...)=2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{i} \sim \ 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{i}  \ \ di=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 43 n^{\frac 32}  $$

So our limit becomes:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\frac 43 n^{\frac 32}}=0$$

:)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}}
 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}} \times \frac{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}
                                             {\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}
 = \frac{\sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}}{(i+1)-i}
 = \sqrt{i+1}+\sqrt{i}
$$